# Celery worker concurrency

Tags: python, django, celery

I have made a scraper to scan around 150 links.
Each link has around 5k sub links to get info from.

I am using Celery to run the scraper in background and store data on a Django ORM. I use `BeautifulSoup` for scrap URL .

When i running the celery using this command

`celery worker -A ... --concurrency=50`

everything working fine but the workers from 1 to 50 sleep

How i can make the celery working till the scraper finish its task?

Comment: show us how your task defined and fired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all that command will not start 50 workers, but 1 worker with 50 processes. I'd also recommend to just use as many processes as you have cores available. (Let's say 8 for the rest of my answer.)

My guess here is that the other processes are idle because you only perform one task. If you want to do concurrent work, you'll have to split up your work in parts that can be executed concurrently. The easiest way to do this is just make a separate task for every link you want to scrape. The worker will then start working on scraping 8 links and when it finishes 1 it will start on the next one until it has finished scraping all 150.

so your calling code of your task should roughly like:

```
for link in links:
    scrape_link.delay(link)
```

with scrape_link your task function that will look something like:

```
@app.task
def scrape_link(link):
    #scrape the link and its sub-links
```

Comment: This mean when u try make each link as task and make the worker concurrency number , will that a good performance

Comment: Yes as long as your concurrency number is at least as high as the number of cores you have, it will be fairly optimal.

Comment: Ok let me try and let you know , that mean if worker start with 20 concurrency , this 20 will be with each task start ?

Comment: No it means the worker will instantiate 20 processes, each process working on one task. If a process is done with its task, it will start with a new task as long there are tasks remaining.

Comment: i have 150 Link , and it will be 150 task is 20 processes will be ok for that

Comment: But why i see when i start with 20 it  decrease to 1 then gone ?

Comment: What exactly do you see decreasing? Are the tasks not executed? What monitoring tools are you using? Try something as simple as putting `print("task starting")` in the beginning of your task, so you can actually see when a task is started.

Comment: When i make concurrency 20 in celery log i see worker-2 , worker3 .... worker20 , after some time i see worker 2 and worker 3 , after few then i see worker2 only , then nothing happen

Comment: Try posting your log in your original question. Maybe there is an issue with your local setup. Which message broker do you use?

Comment: Hi this what i was meaning scrapper stop like appear in this image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-BRgV7pEHMrPOFZYunj19qlAen08lbiQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what's happening in your picture. It looks like only process 20 is doing any work at the end and then I assume it finishes its task. Why do you think celery is the issue? As mentioned before, it might really be useful to post more info in your original post. Your actual code might be helpful, your logs, what you expect to happen exactly. I don't actually see celery misbehaving in any way.

Comment: Ok could u give me your Github account i could share the code with u ?

The last line in terminal is a new link to start scrap