# How to properly configure Celery concurrency based on number of CPU core?

Tags: python, celery

I try to understand how the `concurrency` parameter impact `Celery` tasks execution based on number of CPU core.

According to this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47953914/3423825) it's recommended to limit the number of process to the number of CPU core. In my case the server has 2 CPU so I should run a worker with only 2 processes, which is very restrictive for my application because I would like to execute tens of short tasks (< 5s) in parallel.

I tried to execute more processes and see what happen.

```
celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency 4 -Q default
```

This test executs a task in // that wait 6 seconds.

**Test**

```
from billiard.process import current_process

@app.task(bind=True, name='Test')
def test(self):

    task_id = self.request.id[:3]
    process_id = current_process().index

    log.info('Task {0} start with process {1}'.format(task_id, process_id))

    time.sleep(6)

    log.info('Task {0} complete'.format(task_id))
```

Now, when I execute the task 4 times I see that all tasks are executed in parallel.

```
for i in range(4):
    test.delay()


2022-04-25 10:27:04.519596 [info     ] Task 43c start with process 0               [trading.tasks]
2022-04-25 10:27:04.522944 [info     ] Task f1c start with process 2               [trading.tasks]
2022-04-25 10:27:04.527985 [info     ] Task a85 start with process 3               [trading.tasks]
2022-04-25 10:27:04.528611 [info     ] Task 1a4 start with process 1               [trading.tasks]
2022-04-25 10:27:10.528908 [info     ] Task 43c complete                           [trading.tasks]
2022-04-25 10:27:10.530390 [info     ] Task f1c complete                           [trading.tasks]
2022-04-25 10:27:10.534873 [info     ] Task a85 complete                           [trading.tasks]
2022-04-25 10:27:10.536585 [info     ] Task 1a4 complete                           [trading.tasks]
```

I did the same test with 16 tasks and `concurrency 16` and all tasks were executed in parallel with processes from 0 to 15, despite the server has only 2 CPUs core. It seems there is no limit to the number of process.

**Questions**

Can I execute 50 processes and run 50 tasks or is there a limit before a crash happen ? If there is a limit, then what determine the maximum number of processes ? Any clarification would be appreciate.

Tasks in this example are not CPU intensive so do you think it could explain why they were executed at the same time ?

Thanks!

**CPU core**

```
user@ubuntu-2cpu-4gb-de-fra1:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
```

Comment: Nothing stops you from telling Celery worker to spawn 50 worker processes. However, if you run 50 CPU-bound (computationally heavy) tasks they may run painfully slow on a 2 CPU core machine as system will constantly switch from one process to another... This is why you should limit Celery concurrency to N where N is number of cores, if your tasks are CPU-bound. If they are IO-bound then you should try `gevent` or `eventlet` concurrency type.

Comment: `system will constantly switch from one process to another` now I understand better, thanks